# C# delegate Func

Tags: c#, delegates, func

I came across a line of code that i can't seem to grasp

Let me explain a little.

What i do understand is that with the following line i am defining a type of delegate with the name "myDelegate". This type can hold a pointer to a function with signature int (int, int)

```
public delegate int myDelegate(int a, int b);
```

What i do not get is the following line:

```
public delegate T Func<T>(T a, T b);
```

I mean why would i define a type called Func which is already defined in the .NET framework ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it certainly seems like a bad idea to declare your own delegate when one with the same name and number of generic type parameters is available in the framework - but it's not *invalid*. I suggest that if this is code you own, you rename it appropriately. Note that it's not the same as `Func<T>` as it's using `T` for both inputs and the output. You might want to call it `BinaryOperator` or something similar (although binary operators don't have to have the same operand types, nor does the return value have to be of the same type).

Comment: Additionally, since the OP said they "came across this code", I guess it's possible it was written before `System.Func<T>` was introduced in .Net 3.5.

Comment: @Sven: True. I always forget which `Action` and `Func` overloads were present in .NET 2. Was it just `Action<T>`?

Comment: `Action<T>` was in .Net 2.0; `Action` (non-generic) and `Func<T>` (and its generic overloads) were not.

Comment: probably someone was trying "to extend" the generic delegates available in the Framework.I know it is not a good idea but that is what is loos like to me

Comment: If i replace Func with [var] which is also a reserved word it also works
But if i replace Func with [int] or [while] it does not work.

Can you also explain this please ?

Comment: @HerbalMart: `Func` *isn't* a reserved word. It's just the name of a delegate type. And `var` is only a *contextual* keyword - you can declare a variable or type called `var`, it's just a really bad idea to do so.

Answer (score 0):

the Func syntax is there as a convenience, and often it is better to standardise on what they provide IMHO.

Func and Action are both convenient and easy to remember.  By contrast, I find the delegate syntax a little clumsy.

Comment: `Func` isn't "syntax" - it's just a family of framework-provided delegates. When you say you "find the delegate syntax a little clumsy" - do you mean the syntax for declaring a new delegate type?

Comment: yes that is what I mean.  Just that I prefer seeing them expressed in this way.  No it's not C# syntax, but you can incorporate the provided delegates into your style.  Your distinction is a useful one though.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET `Func<T>` is different:

```
T Func<T>();
T2 Func<T1, T2>(T1 arg);
T3 Func<T1, T2, T3>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2);
.. etc
```

The delegate definition is not wrong, it's the naming that will get confusing with the .NET version.